# How can I show template variables from articles with getResources?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-getresources

I want to use "getResources" to show the articles from the "articles" extra on my homepage.

Here is the code of my homepage:

```
[[getResources? &parents=`52` &tpl=`sample.ArticlesLatestPostTpl` &showHidden=`1` &includeContent=`1`   &includeTVs=`1` &processTVs=`1`  ]]
```

and this is my `sample.ArticlesLatestPostTpl`:

```
<li>
[[*myimage]]
  <a href="[[~[[+id]]]]">[[+pagetitle]]</a>
  [[+publishedon:notempty=`<br /> - [[+publishedon:strtotime:date=`%b %d, %Y`]]`]]
</li>
```

My template variable is `[[*myimage]]`

But I cannot see the template variable of the article. Instead I see the template variable of the homepage.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

Instead of `[[*myimage]]` I need to write `[[+myimage]]`.

And working! :)

Answer (score 1):

It works like this:

- [[*image]] will display the data inside field "image" of the current
  document.
- [[+image]] will display the data inside field "image" of all
  resources you might query from the current document.
- [[+tv.image]] may
  work too, if you use "getResources" that uses "tv." as a Template
  Variable prefix as default.

Best info if you are in doubt are those two pages:

General tag syntax:
https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/tag-syntax

and default tags that are used now and then:
https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/commonly-used-template-tags